# Dealing with asynchrony (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, concurrency, nsurlsession

I'm currently making an app and I having a problem with asynchrony. Multiple times in the app I have to load film objects from the site, put them in an array and then define the array of the view controller to this array of films using completionHandlers. In two different but similar scenarios this goes wrong:

1. These film objects need to be displayed in a UICollectionView, but numberOfItemsInSection is called before there is anything in the array causing the app to crash with a index out of range error. The array is an **array of arrays** (array of film objects for every UITableViewCell)
2. Depending on genres I want to display I load the film objects from the site. The genres are also loaded from the site to keep the code flexible to changes. The genres are then saved in a **dictionary**. By the time I need to use the genres to load the movies the genres array is still empty.

What is the best way to go about the two and why?

**Note:**
Yes I know about **didSet** but I need the row number to know which key to use which then enables me to load these film object arrays.

**EDIT:**
Some code to maybe clarify the situation

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        //The moved this method to viewDidLoad() but it isn't done in time
        //Added this hear so you guys get an idea where genres come from

        getCategories(completionHandler: { genres in
            self.genres = genres
        })

        // The code crashes when I want to perform this method                      
        // because the genres array is still empty here, 
        // I don't know how to do it otherwise because I need   
        // indexPath.row to know which commando to use to load the 
        // film objects of a certain genre (the one that is related to this row)

        test(ID: genres[currentlyUsedGenres[indexPath.row]]!, completionHandler: { loadedMovies in
            self.loadedList.append(loadedMovies)
        })

        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.movieLabel.setTitle(listNames[indexPath.item], for: .normal)

        cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.movieLabel.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell

}
```

Comment: If you're crashing due to `index out of range` then you're definitely doing it wrong.  Base your number of cells on the count of your array, and you won't have to worry about creating more cells than you have data for.  Load your films asynchronously, and when it's done call `reloadData()` on your collection view and all your newly loaded data will be displayed.  You may have to deal with a loading animation or something if your film fetch takes a long time.

Comment: there are over 7000 google results for 'swift anysnchronous collectionview' - many of those are tutorials that will show you exactly how to do this

Comment: I will edit the question a bit, but it is actually an array of arrays so for one row of the tableviewcell I need one element of this array of arrays. But its still empty when numberofitemsinsection gets called

Comment: Yes, @symenize - that is why you reload the collectionView after your arrays are filled out.

Comment: yeah I understood, but what would I have to return in this numberofitemsinsection? Because I can not say for example return movieArray[1].count because it does not exist yet

Comment: I'm confused by your combination of collection view and table view.  Assuming each collection cell contains a table (?), does the crash happen while providing collection data or table data?  (Hint: showing code would reduce the confusion.)

Comment: every tableviewcell has a collectionview, so when i know the row of the cell in the table view I know which movie objects to load because every tableviewcell is a genre, but by using only didSet I don't know the films I have to load of what genre, sorry for the confusion, I will try to add code

Comment: @PhillipMills edited the question again

Comment: The only thing you should be doing in that function is configuring a cell and returning it.  Changing the backing data is too dangerous to consider.  If you don't have data available, tell the table there are no rows in that section, then reload the table when the data exists. (Aside: You also seem to be using two different arrays for cell data (`genres` and `listNames `), which is usually a source of other problems.)

Comment: What do you do in `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: @PhillipMills this worked thanks a lot!